# If $f$ is convex, $g$ is multilinear, and $f=g$, $\nabla f=\nabla g$ in two points, is $f\ge g$ everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f(x,y):\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be convex, and let $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ be distinct points. Define $g(x,y)=a x y+b x+cy+d$ to be the unique multilinear function that agrees with $f(x,y)$ in $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ and such that $\nabla g$ agrees with $\nabla f$ in those points as well. (This defines 6 equationis in $a,b,c,d$. We only care about the cases where this system is solvable.)

Can we say that $f(x,y) \ge g(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$?

If $f$ was a one-argument convex function $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, we would know that if $f$ agreed with a linear function in a point, and also agreed with its derivative, then $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

I'm wondering if the same thing holds in two dimensions? Or if not, are there any further requirements we can put on $f$ such that this global condition holds?

In particular, I'm interested in whether this holds for the function $f(x,y) = h(x)h(y)$ where $h(x)=((1+x)^s+(1-x)^s)^{1/s}$ for some $s\in[1,2]$.

**Update:** Ok, a counterexample is $f(x,y)=|x+y|$, which agrees with $g(x,y)=x y+1$ at $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$ and $(1,1)$, but clearly $xy+1>|x+y|$ for $x$ and $y$ large enough.

The question should then really be if *products of* convex functions (that is $f(x,y)=h_1(x)h_2(y)$) have the property mentioned above.

**Update 2:** So another counterexample is $f(x,y)=|x|y$ which of course agrees with $xy$ on all of $x\ge 0$, but $|x|y\le xy$ for $x\le0,y\le 0$.

It still appears to hold for my example function, but maybe we also need to assume that $h_1=h_2$ or that the functions are non-negative.

Comment: $g$ is not linear.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. I have updated it to "multilinear". I meant that it was linear in each variable separately.

Comment: Moreover, $\nabla f = \nabla g$ in two points yields four equations, since the gradient has two components.

Comment: @gerw, You are right. I suppose we should either not care about the magnitude of the gradient (stronger) or only consider the cases where the 6-equation system is solvable (weaker). I'd be interested in progress / counterexamples for either case.

Comment: One observation is that $axy+bx+cy+d$ can be written as $(a'x+b')(c'y+d')+e$. If $e=0$ and $h_1$ and $h_2$ are log-convex, then we have $h_1(x)h_2(y) \ge (a'x+b')(c'y+d')$ if they agree in just one point. The issue is then $e\neq 0$.